# Android sms receiver service

Tags: android, service, sms

I'm trying to create an android service that take incoming messages and if it equals to specific string hides the SMS and use it for the app.

For now when i'm trying to debug nothing happens. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
My app doesn't need any UI

My code now is:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cyberApp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <receiver
        android:name="com.cyberApp.MyService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.cyberApp.MainMen"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

MainMen:(The service that supposed to run and run the sms receiver)

```
package com.cyberApp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainMen extends Service {
public MainMen() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

private MyService mSMSreceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("where", "OnCreate");
    //SMS event receiver
    mSMSreceiver = new MyService();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    // Unregister the SMS receiver
    unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
}
}
```

MyService: (The SMS Reciver)

```
package com.cyberApp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {
// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();


public MyService() {
    Log.e("bahh", "Bahhhh");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to create an activity to display any UI?

Comment: @bdavies6086 I don't want any UI, this is the main problem i guess.

Comment: Have you considered creating an activity but making the background transparent?

Comment: @bdavies6086 No, But I'll try that now.
should it somehow interact with the service?

Comment: Well, you'd have the service use an intent to create the activity, then the activity would have your toast code within its onCreate method

Comment: @bdavies6086 thanks for your answers, just something i need to be cleared, what is the order of operation of my app should be? when i start the debugging which file is first to run?

Comment: Well it'd be setting the broadcast receiver from the service, so the service would be the first to run, followed by the broadcast receiver when the message arrives then followed finally by the activity